# Need to call simple request from soundcloud API using the wrapper

Tags: php, api, request, wrapper, soundcloud

I am using the main soundcloud wrapper (https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud) to try and pull the tracks off my account onto my website. I had the whole thing working great but just by accessing a query (my username has changed and isn't as unique, so i need to change the query). So what I need to request is exactly this "https://api.soundcloud.com/users/isound604/tracks.json" and if you check in the API console you will see it returns my tracks.

My problem is that i don't know how to make this request with the wrapper. I used to use:

```
$string = $soundcloud->get('tracks', array('q' => 'beatmanshan', 'order' => 'created_at'));
```

but the new request doesn't seem to work in that function. Can anybody shed any light on this issue? Please and thank you in advance! Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already authenticated ok using the api?  To check

```
$my_details = json_decode($soundcloud->get('me'));
```

Should return your account details

If so have you tried

```
$string = $soundcloud->get('users/isound604/tracks', array('order' => 'created_at'));
```